# YOLO (Darknet) with Jetson Nano: How can i do parallel detections?

Tags: darknet, nano

The Darknet guide to detect objects in images using pre-trained weights is here

I am using Darknet with the command to run like this:

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg
```

Is there a way to do parallel detections? Of course i can start just parallel the same command, but the detection become very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use some framework to load the weights (Tensorflow, or PyTorch) and then you will have full control on the model, check this repository for a tensorflow implementation:

https://github.com/aloyschen/tensorflow-yolo3